# java heap space while writing 86000 rows with .xlsm excel using xssf

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsm

java heap space raised while writing 86000 rows with .xlsm excel using poi

```
xssfworkbook at hhhhCell = hhhhRow.createCell(j + colNumber);
hhhhCell.setCellValue(ret.getFieldValueString(sortSequence.get(i), colName));

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.resize(Saver.java:1592)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.preEmit(Saver.java:1223)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.emit(Saver.java:1144)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.emitElement(Saver.java:926)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver.processElement(Saver.java:456)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver.process(Saver.java:307)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.saveToString(Saver.java:1727)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor._xmlText(Cursor.java:546)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor.xmlText(Cursor.java:2436)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.xmlText(XmlObjectBase.java:1455)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.getKey(SharedStringsTable.java:130)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.addEntry(SharedStringsTable.java:176)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:345)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:315)
        at prg.util.PbExcelGenerator.buildReportTableXLSM(PbExcelGenerator.java:5233)
        at prg.util.PbExcelGenerator.createExcelForReportsXLSM(PbExcelGenerator.java:3490)
        at com.progen.reportview.bd.PbReportViewerBD.generateReportForExportReportSchedule(PbReportViewerBD.java:14811)
        at prg.reportscheduler.ReportSchedulerJob.sendExportSchedulerMail(ReportSchedulerJob.java:810)
        at prg.reportscheduler.ReportSchedulerJob.execute(ReportSchedulerJob.java:83)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
```

Comment: So.. what is the question?

Comment: i am getting exception like above so please suggest me what to do?

Comment: try to extend the heap when you run the app : java -Xms500m -Xmx1000m -jar ./dist/myJar.jar

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many ways to solve it and at last i got solution like below

I used POI SXSSFWorkbook suggested by someone and it's working fine for me.

```
SXSSFWorkbook hhhhWorkbook = null;
SXSSFSheet hhhhSheet = null;

CellStyle hhhhStyle = null;
Row hhhhRow = null;
Cell hhhhCell = null;


OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(inStream);
XSSFWorkbook xssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
hhhhWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(xssfwb,100); // keep 100 rows in memory, exceeding rows will be flushed to disk
hhhhSheet = (SXSSFSheet) hhhhWorkbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
```